# Run jar's in non-debug mode

Tags: java, maven, debugging, jar

When i run a jar by `java -jar xx.jar` on `Centos`  it run in `debug` mode and that's taking too much time

the `jar` was made by `mvn clean package`

how can i run it without the debug mode?

Comment: What makes you think it's being run in debug mode?

Comment: @Kayaman because it show something like this `[2016-05-11 13:40:06,812][DEBUG] `

Comment: Debug mode usually implies an IDE and breakpoints to me.  Do you really mean "logging at DEBUG level from log4j"?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't running in debug mode, but you are logging at DEBUG level.

Change the log4j.xml from DEBUG to INFO, repackage the JAR, and try again.

Comment: which property exactly should î change?

Comment: Didn't I say log4j.xml?  Look for DEBUG on log level; change it to INFO.